# How to factorize code with Sequelize and get results from my functions?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to do some repetitive stuff in a Sequelize controller like generating a hash.

I would like to not duplicate these lines, not do it as it was a script and do it with a function because I will have to do it at different places.

I have tried to define my function "generateHash" at different places of my controller without success.

This code works

```
module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    var hexTag = shortid.generate();

    let password = req.body.password;
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        return Player
        .create({
            hexTag: hexTag,
            mail: req.body.mail,
            password: hash,
            pseudo: req.body.pseudo
        })
        .then(player => res.status(201).send(player))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
      });
    });
  }
};
```

This code don't

```
module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {

    function generateHash(value) {
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(value, salt, function(err, hash) {
          return hash;
        });
      });
    }

    var hexTag = shortid.generate();

    var hash = '';
    let password = req.body.password;
    generateHash(password).then(function (result) {
      hash = result;
    });

    return Player
        .create({
            hexTag: hexTag,
            mail: req.body.mail,
            password: hash,
            pseudo: req.body.pseudo
        })
        .then(player => res.status(201).send(player))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
};
```

I also tried

`var hash = generateHash(password);`

but I don't know if my function is at the right place and if the way to retrieve the result is right.

I expect to get a hash and my player be created but I get this error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Your function generateHash is asynchronous. It returns undefined. You should receive your result using callback or promises and etc.

```
function generateHash(value, callback) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(value, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if(err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      callback(null, hash);
    });
  });
}
```

To avoid callback hell use lib such as `async` or promises, or async / await.

Then you can get your hash using like that:

```
generateHash(value, ((err, hash) => {
    ...
});
```